# Store data separately using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to collect data-id from a searched page in shutterstock. This is what the HTML looks like

```
<i class="i i-lightbox sstk-icon icon-plus-sign js_lightbox_add" data-id="253869514" data-tooltip-title="Add to a lightbox" data-lightboximageid="253869514" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".lightbox-modal" data-track="click.searchResults-saveToLightboxModal" data-original-title="" title=""></i>
```

I want the value of data-id to get stored so i can print them seperately.

This code for example does not work, it just returns: "None"

```
url = "https://www.shutterstock.com/search/test?autocomplete_id=&language=en&search_source=&version=llv1&image_type=images&safe=true"
r  = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for n in soup.find_all('i'):
    showdata = n.get('data-id')

print showdata
```

And if I change showdata = n.get('data-id') to: print n.get('data-id')
It will return all the data-id's, but all together. So I can not print them all separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
for n in soup.find_all('i'):
    showdata = n.get('data-id')    
    print showdata
```

You'll see that ever iteration you overwrite showdata, and the last elements does not have the class `data-id`.

So this will give you a list of all the non-None matches:

```
all_data_ids = []
for n in soup.find_all('i'):
    showdata = n.get('data-id')
    if showdata:
        all_data_ids.append(showdata)

print all_data_ids
```

Comment: Thanks this helps me alot. This was exactly what i was searching for!

Comment: Glad to help.  :)  Just upvote and except if answers on SO are to your liking

Comment: I cannot upvote now because this is a new account sorry!